# I have one application which was published, if APK is send/installed via xender or any other resources, is it counted at google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have one application which is published, and I send it via xender to my friend, is it count at google play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google play only shows the number of download through Google Play.

You could integrate https://get.fabric.io/ It can count any kind of downloads (Amazon downloads and installs from apk files for example)